# using @PreAuthorize in Spring security with roles and rights

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, authorization

I'm using spring security with user, role, right entities and user is authenticated successfully and I can access its authorities collection.

I use AJAX to call view pages and send json between front end and back end. The problem is that I don't know how to configure my spring-security file because @PreAuthorize annotation doesn't work. My login page is displayed when application is loaded and it redirects to login page in case of bad credentials which is sent from controller with json format. I would be thankful if you can help me to solve the problem.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_RIGHT_READ_USER_LIST')")
//    @Secured("ROLE_RIGHT_READ_USER_LIST")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/findAll", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String findAll(HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Here is my spring-security file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled"/>
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/user/findAll/" access="hasRole('ROLE_RIGHT_READ_USER_LIST')" />

    </http>

<beans:bean id="jdbcAuthenticationProvider" class="com.my.app.spring.JdbcAuthenticationProvider"/>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="jdbcAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

and here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class SecurityHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Autowired
    protected UserService userService;
    @Resource(name = "authenticationProvider")
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String logon(
            @RequestParam(value = "username", required = true) String username,
            @RequestParam(value = "password", required = true) String password,
            HttpServletRequest request) {


      Authentication req = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( username, password );
    Authentication result = authenticationProvider.authenticate( req );
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( result );

    UserDetails userDetails=null;
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
                 userDetails
                        = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            }

    User user = (User)userDetails;


    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> ga = userDetails.getAuthorities();


            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute(SESSION_ATTRIB_USER, user);
            return getJsonSuccessData(user);

        } else {

            return getJsonErrorMsg(ar.getMsg());

        }

    }
```

Comment: Although there are some duplication on your configuration , it seems to be enough to work. Are you sure that the controller that you want to protect is a part of the same context as the Spring Security context is apart of?

Comment: yes there is only one context.

Answer (score 0):

OK,I don't really know how you configured your context, however, I'll paste here a Java based configuration that I'm using :

```
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AdviceMode;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration;

import com.comilion.fw.app.security.MyPermissionEvaluator;


@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class GlobalMethodSecurityCtxConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

}
```

if you are using XML based configuration, just add it to your configuration by using

Comment: isn't this equal to my xml config ? <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled"/>